# TFS 2018 PAT Tokens and AD account password change?

Tags: tfs, token

If I create a Personal Access Token for TFS 2018 for 180 days. If I change my Active Directory password, do I need to update the token or is the token good for 180 days? Do tokens have to be recreated If I change my password in AD?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to recreate PAT if you change your password in AD. PAT and User/Password are different authentication mechanisms.